# How can I do random name picker in multiple textboxes in c# framwork?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, random, visual-c++

I need help with random name picker in multiple textboxes in c# framwork. Can someone help me with how I can get started? How to think? I would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`Enumerable.OfType<TResult>(IEnumerable) Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-5.0) to get the list of all textboxes.

And use [`Random Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-5.0) to generate a random index.

```
private void btnrandompicker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var random = new Random();
    // get textboxes list
    var tblist = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
    var randomtb = tblist[random.Next(tblist.Count)];

    Console.WriteLine(randomtb.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example for winforms in C# language.

```
List<int> numberList = new List<int>();
foreach (Control ctr in this.Controls)
{
    if (ctr is TextBox)
    {
       GenerateRandom:
       Random random = new Random();
       int number = random.Next(125, 900);
       var findNumber = numberList.Find(a => a == number);
       if (findNumber == 0)
       {
          ctr.Name = "txt" + number;
          numberList.Add(number);
       }
       else
          goto GenerateRandom;
   }
}
```